# Alternative solution not using closures

Tags: python-3.x, closures

I have a class `Data` which I want to filter using the below api.

```
# Example: filter using where
inpt = {"a":np.array((1,2,3,4,2,5,6,2,3,3,2,1)), 
         "b":np.random.rand(12)}
data = (Data(inpt)
        .where(col("a").equals(3)) # This is how where should be called. 
       )
data
```

- `where` is a method from class `Data`
- `col("a").equals(3)` is syntactic sugar for  `inpt["a"] == 3`

I am able to achieve this using another class `Expr` which handles all the functionality within `Data.where()` using closures. Reason for this being that `Expr` doesn't have access to `Data`.

**Questions**: can someone provide me with an alternative approach not involving closures. My goal is to learn new approaches / directions.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Dict, Any
import numpy as np

class Data:
    def __init__(self, data: Dict):
        self._data = data
        
    def where(self, e: Expr) -> Data:
        idx = e.collect(self)
        for k,v in self._data.items():
            self._data[k] = v[idx]
        return self
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._data)

class Expr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fs = []
        
    
    def col(self, s: str) -> Self:
        f = lambda x: x._data[s]
        self.fs.append(f)
        return self

    def equals(self, el: Any) -> Self:
        f = lambda x: x == el
        self.fs.append(f)
        return self
        

    def collect(self, x: Data) -> Data:
        args = x
        for f in self.fs:
            args = f(args)
        return args
    
def col(s: str) -> Expr:
    return Expr().col(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the point. Maybe if you give an example of what you're actually trying to do?

If you already know the right key, you can just check directly. If you want to find the right key, the pythonic way is to use a list comprehension.

```
In [2]: inpt = {
   ...:     "a": (1,2,3,4,2,5,6,2,3,3,2,1),
   ...:     "b": 3,
   ...: }

In [3]: inpt["a"] == 3
Out[3]: False

In [4]: inpt["b"] == 3
Out[4]: True

In [5]: [key for key, value in inpt.items() if value == 3][0]
Out[5]: 'b'

In [8]: from typing import Sequence

In [9]: [key for key, value in inpt.items() if isinstance(value, Sequence) and 3 in value][0]
Out[9]: 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really appreciated! My issue is not that I don't know the key. My struggle is that I want to implement the method in such a way that I can call `Data(...).where(col("a").equals(3))`. This is what I want to achieve in the end. My question is how to implement this under the hood in an alternative way to my solution.

Comment: As a side note: the function `equals(3)` is just one simple function. I want to create many different functions that I can call that way.

Comment: My problem is that `col("a").equals(3)` is separate from class `Data` which is why I need to pass over the actual data using a closure. Thankful for other approaches!

Comment: I get that that's the syntax you want. But I'm saying it's not very Pythonic, and if you explained the problem you're trying to solve, there's almost certainly a better way to do it. 
You currently have something that works, and [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68156128/1904146)  is the extensible alternative solution. I'm not quite sure what else you're looking for.